# If $x^2=e,y\neq e$ and $x^{-1}y^2x=y^3$ prove that $O(y)=5$

Tags: group-theory

I tried many ways to prove it but I couldn't find a method to prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only need to prove that $y^5=e$. Note that $x^2=e$ implies $x=x^{-1}$. We have $y^4=(xy^3x)^2=xy^6x$ and $y^6=xy^9x$, so $y^4=x(xy^9x)x=y^9$ and obtain $y^5=1$

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped